# "hatte wiederaufgenommen" or "war wiederaufgenommen worden"?

Tags: verb, past-participle

In conversation with 2 native German speakers, I said

> Arbeit im Hyperstandort **hatte wiederaufgenommen**.

and they corrected me with

> Arbeit im Hyperstandort **war wiederaufgenommen worden**.

But in DWDS I find

> Die Nato **hatte** erst vor gut einer Woche ihren vor zwei Jahren wegen der Ukraine-Krise ausgesetzten Dialog mit Moskau **wiederaufgenommen**.

> Die USA und der sozialistische Karibikstaat **hatten** erst im Juli nach jahrzehntelanger Unterbrechung ihre diplomatischen Beziehungen **wiederaufgenommen**.

> "Heute, genau vier Jahre nachdem unsere Diplomaten gezwungen waren, ihre Botschaft zu verlassen, **haben** wir den Betrieb **wiederaufgenommen**", teilte das israelische Außenministerium am Mittwochabend mit.

Was the correction necessary, or simply a preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see the difference between active and passive voice.

Work itself (=Arbeit) cannot act as a subject (it is being done or being picked up, but not doing something itself, at least in this context).

Instead  the work is being picked up by the employees (or whomever), so it is acted upon. In the examples from DWDS the subject is an entity which actively is picking up something again as opposed in the first sentence where the subject is what is being picked up again.

Maybe this difference gets clearer in a simpler example with essentially the same meaning:

Active voice (the employees picked up work again):

> Die Angestellten hatten die Arbeit wiederaufgenommen.

Passive voice (Work had been picked up by the employees again):

> Die Arbeit war von den Angestellten wiederaufgenommen worden.